# Google Maps for EE, map syles and JSON

Tags: google-maps, json

I used the google map styling wizard to generate this JSON frag.

`[ { "featureType": "road.highway", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.local", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.arterial", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] } ]`

But I have no idea what to do with it. Where do I put this?

Thanks!

Greg

Comment: Have you had chance to take a look at this yet Greg? If so, could you please follow-up and let me know if the answer below was helpful?

Comment: Thanks! I incorporated your comments.  
My template code is now...  
`{exp:gmap:init styles="/js/map_styles.js" style_var="stylez" id="map" class="gmap" style="width:100%;height:450px" map_type="google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP"}`  
map_styles.js contains...  
`var stylez = [ { "featureType": "poi.business", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] } ]`  
But the business featureType is still visible

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented this on a project yesterday, and agree that the [official docs/example](https://www.objectivehtml.com/google-maps/examples/custom-map-styles) is a bit skimpy on details. In any event...

Create a file that includes your JSON object, prefixed with `var stylez =`, save it as "gmap-styles.js" in a place where your browser can see it.

**gmap-styles.js**

```
var stylez = [ { "featureType": "road.highway", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.local", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.arterial", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] } ]
```

Then, use use the `styles` and `style_var` parameters in `{exp:gmap:init}` in your template to specify the path to the JS file, as well as the name of the JSON var you saved in it.

**some.group/some_template.html**

```
{exp:gmap:init 
    ... a bunch of other params ...
    styles="url/path/to/gmap-styles.js"
    style_var="stylez"
}
```

Comment: I was missing the "var stylez =" 
I know have this in my styles file...

var stylez = [ { "featureType": "poi.business", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] } ]

and my map code is...

{exp:gmap:init styles="/js/map_styles.js" style_var="stylez" id="map" class="gmap" style="width:100%;height:450px"  map_type="google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP"}